# javascript regex detect duplicate blank lines

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried to detect duplicate blank lines with

```
\s*\n\n+
```

https://regex101.com/r/v0imUZ/1

but doesn't seem to work with

```
  test1
   
    
   
   test2
   test3
  test4

  test1
   
    
   
   test2
   test3
  test4
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work."  Keep in mind that `\s*` will also match newline characters.

Comment: @Rajesh `/\n{2,}/` matches 2 or more line breaks. OP needs to match two or more *blank lines*. `/\n[^\S]+/` matches a newline and then one or more whitespace chars (not necessarily a newline). Basically, neither is the solution.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew consecutive new lines would mean blank lines. Correct?

Comment: No, those are *empty* lines, not *blank* lines, see the regex demo link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\n(?:[^\S\n]*\n)+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v0imUZ/2). If there can be CRLF endings:

```
\r?\n(?:[^\S\n\r]*\r?\n)+
```

*Details*:

- `\r?` - an optional carriage return symbol
- `\n` - a newline char
- `(?:[^\S\n]*\n)+` - one or more occurrences of

  - `[^\S\n]*` - zero or more whitespace chars excluding newline char, and then
  - `\n` - a newline char.

Answer (score 3):

As commented,

> A simpler way would be /\n{2,}/ or /\n[^\S]+/

you can try `/\n[^\S]*\n/`.

Idea is to check for new line, optionally followed by whitespace character followed by a new line.